# How to insert a new row after the last record of each group in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to insert a new row after each group in SQL Server.

This is the original table

[image: Original Table]

This is the expected output

[image: Expected output]

The problem what I have here I'm not sure how to mix two of them together in a new view I'm creating.

To get the last record:

```
WITH new_students_table AS 
(
    SELECT 
        m.*, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Subject ORDER BY Subject DESC) AS student
    FROM 
        students AS m
)
SELECT * 
FROM ranked_messages 
WHERE student = 1;
```

To get the sum:

```
SELECT 
    [Subject] = COALESCE([Subject], 'Total'), 
    [Score] = SUM([Score])
FROM 
    students
GROUP BY 
    GROUPING SETS(([Subject]), ());
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check out GROUP BY ... ROLLUP https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transact-sql-syntax-conventions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do the trick.

Notice `row_number()` and the first of the `Grouping Sets`

```
Select Subject   = case when StudentID is null Then 'Total '+Subject else Subject end
      ,StudentID 
      ,Score=sum(Score)
 From  (Select *
              ,RN=row_number() over (partition by Subject order by StudentID)
         From  YourTable 
       ) src
 GROUP BY GROUPING SETS( ([Subject],[StudentID],[RN])
                        ,([Subject])
                        );
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: Fantastic John. This helped. As a select query this worked like a charm but when I added this select query inside my view, I get different result. I see a NULL record in the last row with Sum of all the scores.

Comment: `IF EXISTS(SELECT *
          FROM sysobjects
          WHERE name = 'uv_student_detail')
    BEGIN
        DROP VIEW dbo.uv_student_detail
    END
GO

CREATE VIEW dbo.uv_student_detail AS
Select Subject   = case when StudentID is null Then 'Total '+Subject else Subject end
      ,StudentID 
      ,Score=sum(Score)
 From  (Select *
              ,RN=row_number() over (partition by Subject order by StudentID)
         From  @YourTable 
       ) src
 GROUP BY GROUPING SETS( ([Subject],[StudentID],[RN])
                        ,([Subject])
                        );`